# Wish Robert S. Barnes congratulations for reaching 2k points!

Tags: discussion, congratulations

Just wanted to congratulate @RobertS.Barnes for reaching this milestone. You've been on here for a while and always seem to pull out the great thought provoking questions! Don't let up on us now! :D

Comment: Indeed, he seems to always come up with some interesting questions.  Congrats @RoberS.Barnes

Comment: @DucatiKiller Thanks to you both!